# Changes to selected element in scope won't be persisted in array of available elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularJS 1.5.6 and try to update a value by using a combo box within an object that had already being selected through another combo box. But after switching the source object these changes are lost.

For a better understanding try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/olivermue/tbzggyg1/).

Within the above example the first combo box just selects an item out of a list of availables:

```
<select data-ng-model="currentElement"
        data-ng-options="element.name for element in elements track by element.id"
        data-ng-change="updateDeeperOption()">
</select>
```

The second combo box works on a second list of available options:

```
<select data-ng-model="deeperOption"
        data-ng-options="option.name for option in availableOptions track by option.value"
        data-ng-change="writeDeeperOptionToCurrentElement()">
</select>
```

The two method, which are being called whenever a change happens are simply updating the data in both directions:

```
$scope.updateDeeperOption = function() {
    $scope.deeperOption = $scope.availableOptions.filter(function (option) {
        return option.value === $scope.currentElement.going.deeper.to.myOption; })[0];
};

$scope.writeDeeperOptionToCurrentElement = function() {
    $scope.currentElement.going.deeper.to.myOption = $scope.deeperOption.value;
};
```

The problem comes from `writeDeeperOptionToCurrentElement()`. It updates the current element (you can see it within the fiddle), but if you switch to another element and back again, the changes are lost.

Any idea, what I made wrong? I think, I'm still missing some fundamental understanding about when objects are copied or just referenced within AngularJS. So any explanation or links would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update:***

I isolated the actual problem here and found that if you remove the track by from your first select then the currentElement object gets updated by reference. See: https://jsfiddle.net/tbzggyg1/4/

So instead of this:

```
<select data-ng-model="currentElement"
            data-ng-options="element.name for element in elements track by element.id"
            data-ng-change="updateDeeperOption()">
```

Try this:

```
<select data-ng-model="currentElement"
            data-ng-options="element.name for element in elements"
            data-ng-change="updateDeeperOption()">
```

And here is why: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

> ... is to use a **track by** clause, because then ngOptions will track the identity of the item ***not by reference*, but by the result of the track by expression**. For example, if your collection items have an id property, you would track by item.id.

---

*Old answer:*

It looks like your '$scope.currentElement' object is actually just getting a copy reference from the array, so when you make modifications it doesnt really update the original array (which is what your dropdowns bind to). I tried this and it worked:

```
  $scope.writeDeeperOptionToCurrentElement = function() { 
      // $scope.currentElement.going.deeper.to.myOption = $scope.deeperOption.value; // old code

      var elementRef = $scope.elements.filter(isMatchingElement)[0];
      elementRef.going.deeper.to.myOption = "" + $scope.deeperOption.value;
  };
  function isMatchingElement(e) {
    return e.id === $scope.currentElement.id;
  }
```

Also, add this to your template so you can see the entire picture of whats happening:

```
<tt>{{currentElement}}</tt>
<hr>
<tt>{{elements}}</tt>
```

Link to fiddle forked: https://jsfiddle.net/t2dvm0a2/

Comment: So far thank you for that. I thought so, that the object out of the array was copied instead of referenced. Do you know any documentation, blog post, etc. that explains when and why angular (or javascript) uses copies or references?

Comment: This is an interesting one, the docs for ngOptions state many cases where i'd be referenced by copy if certain criteria weren't met (i.e. not using track by or initializing with a value outside the array) but you seem to have covered it pretty well and yet its doing a copy of currentElement. I'm going to keep researching this.

Comment: Check my updated answer, I believe I have found the reason.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the investigation. I really have to closer read about the *track by* clause before using it. ;-)

Comment: @Oliver I actually had to read that thing a couple of times, agree that it is not very clear. Glad to know I helped.

Answer (score -1):

In ng-options each option item is identified by the value you provide in `track by`.

Had you given your deep value in track by, things would have worked.

```
    <select data-ng-model="currentElement"
            data-ng-options="element.name for element in elements track by element.going.deeper.to.myOption"
            data-ng-change="updateDeeperOption()">
    </select>
```

Please check the updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/tbzggyg1/3/

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct. In my example data I used for the ids of the elements and the value of the options the same numbers (my fault), but they don't correlate to each other. Even when I try out your fiddle I see some awkward behaviour if you switch to the second element and then to "some" it switches the the current element back to the first entry.